# ForEach, get value of next property

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, iteration

I'm assigning property values to a class using a `ForEach statement`. Output will look like this...

```
Startingpoint | length
-----------------------
0             | 1
1             | 54.47
55.47         | 47.98
```

So length is calculated like so...

```
length = *next item starting point - current item starting point
```

Here's what I'd like to do in a Pseudo Code esque look.

```
foreach (DefectMap obj in dm)
{
     mdmList.Add(new ModifiedDefectMap()
        {                        
            StartingPoint = obj.Start,
            Length =  ValueOfNext().obj.Start - obj.Start
```

The problem is, I have no way of  telling what `"ValueOfNext().obj.Start"` would be, since I am on the current Itereation of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: 1. option - use for loop 2. option - use `indexof`

Comment: I've fixed the formatting a little. Hope you don't mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a regular for loop

```
//Count-1 to stop at the second to last item
for(int i = 0; i < dm.Count-1; ++i)
{
      mdmList.Add(new ModifiedDefectMap()
      {                        
           StartingPoint = dm[i].Start,
           Length =  dm[i+1].Start - dm[i].Start
      });
}
```

Comment: this works, but I want it to iterate through the last loop, and then set Length to 0, I'm gonna work on figuring this out

Answer (score 3):

You could try a `.Zip()` statement.

```
mdmList = dm.Zip(dm.Skip(1), (current, next) => new ModifiedDefectMap
{
  StartingPoint = current.Start,
  Length = next.Start - current.Start
});
```

The skip offsets the list, so you end up mapping all pairs of adjacent elements to `current` and `next`, and then create the object using them. Seems fairly clean this way.

Comment: I like this zip statement, I've never used it before. Using zip is there an easy way of saying if next == null then Length = 0

Comment: Yeah, it's essentially an anonymous function, so you can do whatever you want in there. You could also make the whole (current, next) part a method of the form: `private ModifiedDefectMap CreateModifiedMap(DefectMap current, DefectMap next)`, and then the zip would become `mdmList = dm.Zip(dm.Skip(1), CreateModifiedMap);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access more then one item at a time you better use `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dm.Count-1; ++i)
{
      mdmList.Add(new ModifiedDefectMap()
      {                        
           StartingPoint = dm[i].Start,
           Length =  dm[i+1].Start - dm[i].Start
      }
}
```

If you still want to use  `foreach` loop you can use `IndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly sure if you can look at the next value within a `foreach` but, if you are doing an implementation like that I would suggest using a for loop to provide the next value, just be sure to check if the would-be next value is within the bounds of the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
     list[i] = random.Next();
     if(i+1 < list.Length)
     {
         list[i+1] = random.Next();
     }
}
```

Just be sure to understand that you need list to have an indexer (the [x] array notation) because some collections do not have that, such as HashSet or Stack.

Answer (score 1):

Several options suggest themselves.

1. Make the collection (`dm`)  a linked list instead of whatever it is.
    Then you could write

   ```
    while(obj.next != null)
    {
       var length =  obj.Next.Start - obj.Start;
       // whatever else you need to do in iteration
    }
   ```
2. Add a property to each object, named `Collection` containing a reference to the collection `dm`, and another property named `End`.

   ```
    public double? End // has to be nullable double to return null on last item
    { 
      get 
      { 
          var nDx = Collection.IndexOf(this);
          return Collection.Count > nDx+1?  Collection[nDx + 1].Start: (double?)null;
      }
    }
   ```